# Ruby SSH MySQL Sequel (or DataMapper) remote connection with keys using Net::SSH gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, authentication, ssh, rubygems

How would I connect to my VPS based MySQL database remotely (from a cloud based app) using the Ruby [Net::SSH](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) or [Net::SSH::Gateway](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh-gateway) gems and key, not password, authentication?

And then connect to the database with Sequel or DataMapper. I'm assuming that after I manage to get the SSH connection working, I would just setup a Sequel/DM connection to 'sql_user@localhost:3306/database'.

I did locate a couple of similar question here, but they all use password authentication, not keys, and only demonstrate executing raw commands to query the database.

UPDATE: I just cannot seem to get this (Net::SSH with key manager) to work.

UPDATE2: Alright I have managed to get authorization when logging in from a computer that has authorized keys stored in the users local .ssh folder, with the following (port is my custom SQL port on the VPS):

```
 sql_gate = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('192.xxx.xxx.xx','sqluser', port: 26000)
```

However, I will not be able to create a `.ssh` folder in the app's VM, so I need to somehow pass the path and filename (I will be creating a public key just for SQL access for specified user) as an option ... but haven't been able to figure out how.

UPDATE: Just need to figure out DataMapper access now. Current code being tested (`remote_user_sql` is my Ubuntu user, `sql_user` is the MySQL database user with `localhost/127.0.0.1` privileges):

```
require 'net/ssh/gateway'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-mysql-adapter'

class User
  include DataMapp......
  .
  .
end

ssh_gate = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('192.n.n.n','remote_user_sql', {port: 25000, keys: ["sql_rsa"], keys_only: true})

port = ssh_gate.open('localhost',3306,3307)
  child = fork do
    DataMapper.setup(:default, {
      adapter: 'mysql',
      database: 'sql_test',
      username: 'sql_user',
      password: 'passwd',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: port})
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
    exit
  end
  puts "child: #{child}"
  Process.wait

ssh_gate.close(port)
```

Comment: It seems there is a KeyManager method in the Net::SSH gem (http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH/Authentication/KeyManager.html), but I cannot determine how to implement it properly.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the answer, and will add it here once I've verified it works. It seems that Net::SSH::Gateway takes all the options that Net::SSH does, so you can use `keys: ["/path/to/my_rsa"]` to specify private key file and its location (note that it must be an array). This combined with the Net:SSH:Gateway open method to forward a local port to 3306 on remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, in two parts:

Well I have figured how to make the Net::SSH::Gateway gem using a specified keyfile, and then connect to the VPS through ssh via a port other than 22:

**Part 1: Net::SSH::Gateway key authentication**

First you must generate the keyfiles you want to use, copy the `.pub` to the remove server and append it to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (`cat sql_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`), and then make sure `user_sql` (the user I created on the VPS to be used only for this purpose) has been added to `AllowUsers` list in `sshd_config`. Make note of port used for ssh (25000 for this example) and use the following code to establish the connection:

```
ssh_gate = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('192.n.n.n','user_sql', {port: 25000, keys: ["sql_rsa"], keys_only: true})
```

That will read the keyfile `sql_rsa` in the same directory as script file, then create a new ssh gateway for 'user_sql'@'192.n.n.n' on port 25000.

I can successfully execute raw shell commands on the remove VPS with:

```
ssh_gate.exec("ls -la")
```

To close:

```
ssh_gate.shutdown!
```

Unfortunately I am still having problems using DataMapper (do-mysql-adapter) to use the gateway. I will update this answer if I figure that part out, but at least the first half of the problem has been solved.

These are the errors that DataMapper::Logger has reported:

When `127.0.0.1` was used:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (code: 2002, sql state: HY000, query: , uri: )
```

When `localhost` was used:

```
Access denied for user 'user_sql'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (code: 1045, sql state: 28000, query: , uri: )
```

When the VPS `hostname` was used:

```
Unknown MySQL server host 'hostname' (25) (code: 2005, sql state: HY000, query: , uri: )
```

UPDATE (No success yet): So far the only way I can access the remote MySQL database is by using Net::SSH::Gateway to establish a gateway, and then use the `.ssh`method to open a new Net::SSH connection over that gateway, like so:

```
ssh_gate.ssh('192.n.n.n','user_sql',{port: 25000, keys: ["sql_rsa"], keys_only: true}) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec("mysql -u sql_user -p'passwd' -h localhost -P 3306 -e 'SELECT DATABASE();'")
end
```

In other words, I can only execute SQL commands using the mysql command line. I cannot figure out how to get Sequel or DataMapper to use the gateway to connect.

**Part 2: DataMapper/Sequel/mysql2 connection through Net::SSH::Gateway**

Make sure your MySQL server is bound to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, setup your connection - DataMapper example:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, {
  adapter: 'mysql',
  database: 'DATABASE',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'passwd',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3307}) # local port being forwarded via Net::SSH:Gateway
```

Followed by any `class` table definitions and `DataMapper.finalize` if required. Note that DataMapper doesn't actually connect to the remote MySQL server until either an `auto_upgrade!`, `auto_migrate!`, or query is executed, so no need to create the forwarded port yet.

Then create a new Net::SSH::Gateway, and then whenever you need DataMapper/Sequel to access the remote database, just open a port for the process, like so:

```
port = ssh_gate.open('127.0.0.1',3306,3307)
  child = fork do
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade! # DM call that accesses MySQL server
    exit
  end
  Process.wait
ssh_gate.close(port)
```

You may want to put the Net::SSH::Gateway/.open code in a `begin..ensure..end` block, `ensure`'ing the port closure and gateway shutdown.

I had to use a `fork` and `Process.wait` to establish the connection, without it the method just hangs.